# My can i make my NodeJS server wait for a function call? My program is finishing too fast

Tags: node.js, async-await

The following code from the code pasted below it is too fast as the call to:

```
    global.h2=jsonifiedver(l.number)
```

is too slow. How can i make it wait on getting an answer back from jsonifiedver() function call so i can get a correct answer. I tried using global variables, these work, but only after every second call, and plus so that's how i know the call works, it's just that program is ending too fast and then on the second call it has the data i want. I'm new to nodejs so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    var body = ''
    req.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data
      global.l = JSON.parse(body)
      l = JSON.parse(body)

      global.h2=jsonifiedver(l.number) // This call is slow and doesnt 
                                       // finish in time
      global.h3 = JSON.stringify(h2) 
      console.log('Partial body: ' + body, global.l, global.l.number)
    console.log("POST")
    res.end("Not The real end");
    })
  } else {
    console.log("GET")
  }
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // 'text/plain');
  console.log(global.l)
  res.end(global.h3); //"End");
});
```

so res.end(global.h3) finishes before my function call to global.h2=jsonifiedver(l.number) finishes. So i don't get the answer i need. Does that make sense?

Comment: What exactly does `jsonifiedver()` do?

Comment: That's a program i wrote, i just returns a list of numbers from a math formula. It' a big list that's jsonified. Is there a way to call a function and have it wait before continuing in nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is because, when the request is invoked, `req.on('data', function(){})` is just adding a hook for `data` event, but you are also returning the response using `res.end()` after `else` statement. You should not send response back unless the `req.on('end')` is triggered, which implies that the request data has ended. In `data` event, you should ideally just append the data to `body`, and then on `end` event handler you should process the body and return the response. Like follows:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const methodType = req.method;
  if (methodType === "GET") {
    console.log("GET");
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    console.log(global.l);
    res.end(global.h3);
  } else if (methodType === 'POST') {
    console.log("POST")
    var body = ''
    req.on('data', function(data) { 
        body += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
      global.l = JSON.parse(body);
      l = JSON.parse(body);
      global.h2=jsonifiedver(l.number);
      global.h3 = JSON.stringify(h2);
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      console.log(global.l);
      res.end(global.h3);
    });
  }
});
```

And if you are looking for waiting till `jsonifiedver()` call is done, make sure its defined as a `Promise` / `Async` function and then you can call it using `await`, make sure the wrapper function where you are invoking `jsonifiedver()` is defined `async` too.

Comment: Wow, this change works without having to use async. Thank you, i'm still learning, but i will research into async functions as well, as i want to master those, but this solution worked perfectly. I was actually hoping to learn about some async, but this is great, thanks Siddhesh!